# Bar-code reader without ZXing

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am working on a project, which needs bar code reader. My question is that Can we make an app that reads bar code without use of ZXing library.? Actually I don't have Idea about bar code reader.
           If we can, so please tell me how to do it.?

Comment: If you don't want to use the Zxing library
you have to write Ur own library that will decodes the data matrix , 1-d bar codes and 2-d Bar codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another library for barcode reading named zbar

https://github.com/bobftw/zbarSDK

Comment: there is no support data matrix currently
 
http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/feature-requests/76/